# SQL enforce string format on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, datetime-format

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64)

I have a string column that is populated with a date.

The problem is that some of the dates come in the format: `Oct 17 2017  9:21AM`. I need to enforce this format on the column: `2018-01-15 11:22:11.999`

I did some research and I know I can set constraints with CHECK () at table creation or I know I can use ISDATE('2014-05-01') but I don't have an end to end solution.

- I can clean the current data so this constraint is just for future inserts.
- I am looking for a simple solution.

> Any ideea? Any suggestion would be much appreciated

**EDIT :**

**Is a legacy solution. I know is a bad approach but I can not change the format of the field! Only relevant solutions to the problem please.**

Comment: That's the wrong approach. Do **not** store dates in `VARCHAR` columns. Store them in a `DATE` column

Comment: As the type is `VARCHAR`, why will you format it on the column? You can format it when you will show the dates in presentation layer. And the best suggestion would be: store date values in `Datetime` typed column

Comment: Guys, I know! I have to work with it as it is. I can not change the field format

Comment: Then you've lost. You say you want to enforce an arbirtrary, unsortable, unindexable format but not do the easiest thing possible, use the correct problem-free data type

Comment: *Maybe*, you could use `TRY_PARSE` with a hard-coded `en-US` culture  (that's a US specific format). That won't help with the values' unsortability

Comment: *Another* option would be to turn the tables - create a proper `datetime` column and add a calculated column that uses `FORMAT` to generate the string from the `datetime` value. Perhaps add a trigger (probably a BEFORE) that updates the `datetime` column each time an application tries to update the string field

Comment: As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed - do not store dates as string. Store them as as DATE or DATETIMEOFFSET. Then the presentation layer must take care of the formatting (how to display them)

Comment: I know but I can't do that. Only relevant solutions to the problem, please.

Comment: Create a view with correctly formatted columns.

Comment: By "enforce", do you mean the table already contains invalid dates that you want to convert now, or do you mean the table should be changed so that nobody can offer dates in any but the allowed format anymore, or possibly both? Is `2018-01-15 11:22:11.999` (complete with three millisecond digits) the *exact*, *only* format you wish to have/allow or are there others? The simplest answer I can think of is adding a `CHECK` constraint with a simple `LIKE`, but that may not be sophisticated enough.

Comment: I just need to enforce it for future inserts. It doesn't need to be complicated. I am looking for a simple solution.

Comment: If you're allowed to assume the dates are all *valid*, just possibly not in the right *format*, doing an `ALTER TABLE T WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_ValidDate CHECK ([Date] LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]')` will enforce that the date must look like `9999-99-99 99:99:99.999`. This will still allow plenty of invalid dates, of course. (Including that very value.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert that looks good. Thank you

Comment: @JeroenMostert You might tighten this concept by using closer patterns where appropriate (e..g `[0-1]` instead of `[0-9]` for the month's index...

Comment: @Shnugo: on the one hand, you're right, on the other, I don't want anyone reading the pattern to get the impression it can *really* guard against invalid dates. Tightening it down so that "some more" invalid dates would be caught (but not, say, month 13) isn't really effective enough; at that point I'd only settle for a solution that's guaranteed to catch *all* invalid dates. For the weak solution, I'm personally OK with something that's as weak as "yes, it's a digit".

Comment: @JeroenMostert fair point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to stick with this you might add a computed column like here:

```
CREATE TABLE test(SomeSillyDate VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2018-01-15 11:22:11.99')
                       ,('Oct 17 2017  9:2')
                       ,('invalid date');
GO
ALTER TABLE test ADD CheckedDate AS TRY_CAST(SomeSillyDate AS DATETIME);
GO
SELECT * FROM test;
GO
DROP TABLE test;
```

But - if there's any chance - you should store this as `DATETIME` typed value.

You might use a `VIEW` with the tables name *on top* of a new table. This would not change the approach from outside...

### UPDATE: Trigger approach

```
CREATE TABLE test(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeSillyDate VARCHAR(100));
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TestTrigger ON  test 
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    WITH UpdCTE AS
    (
        SELECT t.SomeSillyDate AS oldValue
              ,ISNULL(FORMAT(TRY_CAST(i.SomeSillyDate AS DATETIME),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),t.SomeSillyDate) AS newValue
        FROM test AS t
        INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON t.ID=i.ID
    )
    UPDATE UpdCTE
    SET oldValue=newValue;

END
GO
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2018-01-15 11:22:11.99')
                       ,('Oct 17 2017  9:2')
                       ,('invalid date');
GO
UPDATE test SET SomeSillyDate = GETDATE() WHERE ID=2;
GO 
SELECT * FROM test;
GO
DROP TABLE test;
```

Comment: No chance to change it :(

Comment: @doremifasolasido not even create a BEFORE trigger that makes the change invisible? In any case, you could use `TRY_PARSE` or `TRY_CAST` in a CHECK clause

Comment: @doremifasolasido Are you allowed to add a trigger?

Comment: trigger is ok, I can add it

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Could you help me with a trigger implementation for it?

Comment: @doremifasolasido see my udpate

Comment: @Shnugo I will check it with a colleague but it looks good. Thanks